# How to use multiple checkbox and dropdown lists in a single form in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have one checkbox and two dropdown lists, and I want to have multiple values from the checkboxes and single value from the lists. This is the simplest form of the code I have tried.

```
<?php

$answers = $_POST['answers'];
print_r($answers);

?>

<form action="" method="post" >

<label>Language</label>
<input type='checkbox' name="answers[]" value="java"/> java
<input type='checkbox' name="answers[]" value="c"/> c 
<input type='checkbox' name="answers[]" value="python"/> python

<label>Gender</label>
<select name = "answers[]">
<option value = "Male">Male</option>
<option value = "Female">Female</option>
</select>

<label>Country</label>
<select name = "answers[]">
<option value = "USA">USA</option>
<option value = "UK">UK</option>
<option value = "Canada">Canada</option>
</select>

<input type='submit' value='Submit' />

</form>
```

The result I got is:

```
Array ( [0] => java [1] => c [2] => Male [3] => UK )
```

However, the desired outcome would be

```
Array ( [0] => java, c [1] => Male [2] => UK )
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want multiple checkbox options to be selectable, then what is wrong with those multiple selected options being shown in your results array? The results array you say is desired indicates you _don't_ want multiple checkboxes to be selectable.

Comment: Any specific reason for all fields to have the same name? Why not `<select name="gender">` and `<select name = "country">`?

Comment: If you want `[0] => java, c`, you'd have to either modify the data upon submit, or `implode` the `answers[]` array upon receipt. There are obvious problems though if all your inputs have the same name.